# MySQL can select litral emoji but wont store emoji into table

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf8mb4

I am trying to insert some emoji characters into a table in MySQL, but values are stored as question marks (????).

I made sure to create the database with the proper `utf8mb4` encoding:

[image]
[image]

```
mysql> describe users;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(191) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Then I tried to make sure, does MySql understand emoji or not, so I did this:

```
mysql> select '';

+------+
|      |
+------+
|      |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I did this:

```
mysql> insert into users (name) values ('');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)
mysql> select * from users;
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
| 21 | فاضل       |
| 30 | سلاحف      |
| 46 | ????       |
| 47 | ????       |
| 48 | ????       |
| 49 | ????       |
+----+------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I don't know what to do to fix that..

** EDIT ** : as requested in the comments, I ran the following command:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                   |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                  |
| character_set_results    | utf8                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                    |
| character_sets_dir       | /static/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Where and how did you specify the character set/encoding of the database connection?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';`

Comment: @CBroe I created the database using Google Cloud SQL instance, and specified the character and collate at the creation time. I also ran an ALTER DATABASE to do the same

Comment: @RickJames I have updated my question to show the variables

Comment: I did not ask what you specified for the table when creating it, but what you specified for the _database connection_ that you are using to submit your `insert` statement to the database.

Comment: @CBroe I am not sure I fully understand your question, but I am guessing, how do I connect to mysql? I am using Google SSH over web browser to type all of the commands above... Can you rephrase the question, please?

Comment: @CBroe maybe this is what you are asking about: `:~$ mysql --host=123.xxx.yyy.zzz --user=root --password`

Comment: @CBroe - the `SHOW` that he provided should answer your connection question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection is set up for utf8; it needs to be set up for utf8mb4.

How did you set it?  Change to whichever of these applies.

- `SET NAMES utf8mb4`
- `PDO(... charset=utf8mb4)`
- `mysqli::set_charset('utf8mb4')`
- etc

Emoji are 4-byte utf8 codes, hence the *four* question marks.